# how to clear unresolved import 'cv2' error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, visual-studio-code

I have installed Python 3.9 on my ubuntu 18.04 desktop, i have already installed two libraries using **pip3 install**
1)opencv-contrib-python
2)opencv-python

Currently i am writing a program in **VSCode** for which i am **importing cv2**

I have already default version of **python 3.6.9** in my computer. When i use default version as interpreter, program seems to be **working fine**.But if i switch the interpreter to newly installed **python 3.9** ,  i get an error
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'**

please someone who has faced such problem and know how to resolve it help me!!!...

Comment: Check which `pip` you are using with `pip -V` versus `python -m pip -V` after you've activated your environment. Also, check that it is indeed installed with `python -m pip freeze`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is as you described: it is due to the use of the Python environment.

The module "`cv2`" is installed in "`lib\site-packages\`" in python3.6.9, but when we use "python3.9" without the module "`cv2`" installed, VS Code is in "python3.9" The module could not be found in "`lib\site-packages\`".

You could use the command "`pip3 --version`" to check the source of the module installation tool, the module is installed in "`lib\site-packages\`" here:

[image]

When using the command "`pip3 show opencv-python`" to check its installation location: (...\python\python38\lib\site-packages)

[image]

Therefore, if you want to use the module "cv2" in "python3.9", please install it in this environment. In addition, it is recommended that you use a [virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments), it will be stored in "lib\site-packages" in the folder of the project so that you could check it more intuitively.